# Can I call a JavaScript function from a tornado template if check?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, tornado

I have a websocket based chatroom that performs translations based on the users desired language in the room. On the python side I populate both the spoken language and the translated language.  I pass these values to a templated html page where I want to make a javascript call in the templated if check which will help me to decide which value to populate in the message window. Is this possible to do?  I keep getting an error stating my return result is invalid.  I have shared what I currently have in my template.  The function getUser() is a javascript function and message is the param passed from python to the template.

```
<div class="message" id="m{{ message["id"] }}">
  {% if message["user"] == getUser() %}
    {% module linkify(message["translation"]) %}
  {% else %}
    {% module linkify(message["transcription"]) %}
  {% end %}
</div>
```

Comment: One way to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% if message["user"] == getUser() %}
```

You say that `getUser()` is a JS function. In that case, it won't work. This is because the templates are compiled at the server but the JS runs on the browser. Hence, `getUser()` function will not run.

Comment: Thanks xyres!  Was trying to get this to work and since I wasn't having success I was wondering if something like this was the case.  Thanks again!